# How/Where to assign CoreData entity's variable to structs's @State variable in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, ios13

I use @State variables *(title, description)* to communicate with the other view (UITextView). That view has a binding string variable *(text)*.

I want to use specific CoreData entity (Item) to update my @State variables, so the text in UITextView is updated when view appears (so UITextView does not appear blank). As far as I understand, I should somehow assign that CoreData entity variable to my @State variable at first and, when I get updates from UITextView on my @State variables, I should save context to my CoreData entity. I use init() for initial assign and I don't get any errors until I get to live preview debugging. I get this error (as a debugger message):

> Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Item'

Also, the text is missing on the preview.

Maybe there's the other way to do what I want?

Here's my code:

**Main view**

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item = Item()
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var description = ""
    init (item: Note)
    {
        self.item = item
        self.title = item.title!
...
 TextView(text: self.$title...
...
TextView(text: self.$details...
...
```

**TextView**

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
...
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
...
```

P.S. when I directly pass (ignoring existence of my @State variables) in CoreData entity's property (e.g. self.item.title) as an argument for UITextView displaying text actually works but I don't know how to save the changes from UITextView to CoreData entity directly

Comment: Don't call Item() since you are injecting an instance in your init method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this.

There is the `@FetchedRequest` way for which there are many tutorials out there.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-fetchrequest-property-wrapper

With that method you would pass the `users` object that you are editing.

Also, you can use an `FetchedResultsController`.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U-4Zon6dbE

This way you can have an `@ObservableObject` with the `CoreData` objects

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller

A `ManagedObject` or `CoreData` object already conforms to `ObservableObject`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject

You don't need to put it in an `@State` you just need to pass the Fetched Object from CoreData.

Also, when the user is done with the object you need to `save` the `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Sorry, can I fetch (using @FetchRequest) the exact same Item() I provide observed item variable with?

Comment: My code actually looks like something like this:
User taps an **ItemView** (which shows CoreData entity variables (title, description) as it's context) in the **ContentView**. I send this selected item back to **ContentView** (using `@State` and `@Binding`). Then I send that item as a variable (`self.selectedItem`) to **DetailView**. In my **DetailView** it is that `@ObservedObject item`. I think I miss logic somewhere

Comment: You don't need the extra `State` and `Binding`. Just use the CoreData object. Look at the SwiftUI Tutorial - Handling User Input. Just replace the  `UserData object` in the tutorial with a `CoreData Object` you want/have `Fetched`. In `LandmarkList` start with your `FetchedResult`.

Comment: Also, If you want a NEW CoreData object one that can't be Fetched you have to create it. `Item()`. Look at the CoreData Programming Guide under Creating and Saving Managed Objects.https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW1